# How to set up datasource with Spring for HikariCP?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, hikaricp

Hi I'm trying to use HikariCP with Spring for connection pool. I'm using jdbcTempLate and JdbcdaoSupport. 
This is my spring configuration file for datasource:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="dataSource.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
    <property name="dataSource.user" value="username"/>
    <property name="dataSource.password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

But unfortunately the following error message is generating:

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>()
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: use oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names

Comment: In the xml parameters this answer and many below define the dataSourceClass name to be something other than Hikari. What is the purpose of defining oracle.jdbc as the dataSourceClassName when what we really want is Hikari datasource?

Comment: Found my answer in the documentation https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby. The parameter dataSourceClassName is actually referring to the jdbc driver class name.

Answer (score 38):

you need to write this structure on your bean configuration (this is your datasource):

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="${hibernate.dataSourceClassName}" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize}" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="${hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout}" />

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${dataSource.url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${dataSource.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${dataSource.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- HikariCP configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>
```

This is my example and it is working. You just need to put your properties on hibernate.properties and set it before:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:hibernate.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Obs.: the versions are 
    log4j: 1.2.16 
    springframework: 3.1.4.RELEASE 
    HikariCP: 1.4.0

Properties file (hibernate.properties):

```
hibernate.dataSourceClassName=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
dataSource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
dataSource.username=admin
dataSource.password=
```

Comment: But How I can use the above config in my java code e.g. HikariConfig  hikariConfig = new HikariConfig(); , how hikarConfig would know to pick the above configured configuration ?

Answer (score 36):

my test java config (for MySql)

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource(){
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring-test"); 
    hikariConfig.setUsername("root");
    hikariConfig.setPassword("admin");

    hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");

    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.cachePrepStmts", "true");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.useServerPrepStmts", "true");

    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

    return dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create a datasource bean in servlet context as:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="dataSourceClassName"
        value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
    <beans:property name="maximumPoolSize" value="5" />
    <beans:property name="maxLifetime" value="30000" />
    <beans:property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />
    <beans:property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exampledb</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="user">root</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="password"></beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="prepStmtCacheSize">250</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="cachePrepStmts">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="useServerPrepStmts">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: just want to note that "useServerPrepStmts" is not recommended to use with MySQL

Comment: @iMysak, it would seem that the Hikari wiki *does* recommend using "useServerPrepStmts=true" if you are on a newer version of MySql (v >= 5.5 ), You can see this here: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration

Comment: Great, thanks for notice @PeterToTheThird. Now it is recommended. https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration/_compare/ad57cbedfdba508d6f509171d15454d37878aed0...73d82adb09f49479fd3b36de5960dfc2a9cf23de

Comment: Some simple tests reveal that `userServerPrepStmts = false` is faster. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65608774/) of Vlad Mihalcea illustrates it too.

Answer (score 4):

Using XML configuration, your data source should look something like this:

```
    <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">  
      <property name="dataSourceProperties" >
        <props>
            <prop key="dataSource.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</prop>
            <prop key="dataSource.user">username</prop>
            <prop key="dataSource.password">password</prop>
        </props>
      </property>  
      <property name="dataSourceClassName"   
                value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">  
          <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />  
    </bean>
```

Or you could skip the `HikariConfig` bean altogether and use an approach like the one mentioned [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki)

Comment: OK.but then how will I declare the datasource bean in spring configuration file?? Can you please help me with some sample code!!!!

Comment: Are you using any Java Config in your Spring configuration or is it all xml?

Comment: No man. Its throwing another exception............................Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder

Comment: Do you have slf4j on your classpath?

Comment: You can download javassist from here http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/

Comment: "dataSourceClassName" is wrong it should be "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" see: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names

Comment: if you use HikariCP 2.6.0 you should set properties directly on HikariConfig object, otherwise this won't fly (tested on new MySQL Connector/J 6.0)

Answer (score 3):

I have recently migrated from `C3P0` to `HikariCP` in a Spring and Hibernate based project and it was not as easy as I had imagined and here I am sharing my findings.

For `Spring Boot` see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490967/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-in-my-spring-boot-app-in-my-application-properties-f/47246045#47246045)

I have the following setup

- Spring 4.3.8+
- Hiberante 4.3.8+
- Gradle 2.x
- PostgreSQL 9.5

Some of the below configs are similar to some of the answers above but, there are differences.

## Gradle stuff

In order to pull in the right jars, I needed to pull in the following jars

```
//latest driver because *brettw* see https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/849
compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.0'
compile('com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.7.6') {
    //they are pulled in separately elsewhere
    exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
}

// Recommended to use HikariCPConnectionProvider by Hibernate in 4.3.6+    
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:4.3.8.Final') {
        //they are pulled in separately elsewhere, to avoid version conflicts
        exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
        exclude group: 'com.zaxxer', module: 'HikariCP'
}

// Needed for HikariCP logging if you use log4j
compile('org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25')  
compile('org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25') {
    //log4j pulled in separately, exclude to avoid version conflict
    exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
}
```

## Spring/Hibernate based configs

In order to get Spring & Hibernate to make use of Hikari Connection pool, you need to define the `HikariDataSource` and feed it into `sessionFactory` bean as shown below.

```
<!-- HikariCP Database bean -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>

<!-- HikariConfig config that is fed to above dataSource -->
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="poolName" value="SpringHikariPool" />
        <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />

        <property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="serverName">localhost</prop>
                <prop key="portNumber">5432</prop>
                <prop key="databaseName">dbname</prop>
                <prop key="user">dbuser</prop>
                <prop key="password">dbpassword</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">
        <!-- Your Hikari dataSource below -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <!-- your other configs go here -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider</prop>
                <!-- Remaining props goes here -->
            </props>
        </property>
 </bean>
```

Once the above are setup then, you need to add an entry to your `log4j or logback` and set the `level` to `DEBUG` to see `Hikari` Connection Pool start up.

## Log4j1.2

```
<!-- Keep additivity=false to avoid duplicate lines -->
<logger additivity="false" name="com.zaxxer.hikari">
    <level value="debug"/>
    <!-- Your appenders goes here -->
</logger>
```

## Logback

Via `application.properties` in `Spring Boot`

```
debug=true
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG
```

Using `logback.xml`

```
<logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```

With the above you should be all good to go! Obviously you need to customize the `HikariCP` pool configs in order to get the performance that it promises.

Comment: I noticed all answers are setting credentials. What if I have a scenario where the credentials are to be set at runtime per http request by requester's credentials? Can I leave them out from the configuration?

Answer (score 2):

This last error is caused by the library SLF4J not being found.  HikariCP has two dependencies: slf4j and javassist.  BTW, HikariDataSource *does* have a default constructor and does not need HikariConfig, see [this link](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).  So that was never the problem.

Comment: I already have SLF4J jar added. Now that error is gone.Can you tell me how to add javassist????????????

Comment: Just download the Javassist 3.18.1-GA jar file from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjavassist) and add it to your class path like you did slf4j.

Answer (score 2):

I found it in http://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp and it works.

Your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Your data.xml

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
/>
```

Your jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dev_db
jdbc.username=dev
jdbc.password=dev
```

Comment: I wrote it in the Baeldung :)

Answer (score 1):

May this also can help using configuration file like java class way.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Autowired
    JdbcConfigProperties jdbc;


    @Bean(name = "hikariDataSource")
    public DataSource hikariDataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        HikariDataSource dataSource;

        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbc.getUrl());
        config.setUsername(jdbc.getUser());
        config.setPassword(jdbc.getPassword());
        // optional: Property setting depends on database vendor
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**How to use it:**

```
@Component
public class Car implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AptSommering.class);


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("hikariDataSource")
    private DataSource hikariDataSource;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

for DB2, please try below configuration.

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource"/>

    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${db.maxTotal}" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="driverType">4</prop>
            <prop key="serverName">192.168.xxx.xxx</prop>
            <prop key="databaseName">dbname</prop>
            <prop key="portNumber">50000</prop>
            <prop key="user">db2inst1</prop>
            <prop key="password">password</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>
```