# HikariCP caught exception: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: null

Tags: java, spring

When i try to integrate spring 3.2.3+HikariCP 2.4.7+jdk7+oracle 11g, i got the problem like "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: null". did there anybody has been resolve this problem? please give me help, thanks in advance!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="200"/>
    <property name="minimumIdle" value="10"/>
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="30000"/>
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="600000"/>
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="cachePrepStmts">true</prop>
            <prop key="prepStmtCacheSize">250</prop>
            <prop key="prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</prop>
            <prop key="useServerPrepStmts">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: i think you have an issue with the properties , i dont really remember where was the issue , but check this config posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172643/how-to-set-up-datasource-with-spring-for-hikaricp#answer-31266322) , it might be helpful

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.... Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question. (Dumping some code and say help isn't really a good format for asking questions). For starters, start by added the full stack trace instead of a snippet. Add more of your configuration for instance.