# Hikari configuration for Mysql using spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, configuration, hikaricp

I have spring boot application using MySQL database. I am using hikari connection pool.

According to this official blog of Hikari https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration, I have to set some properties for performance improvement e.g.

```
dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize=250
dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
dataSource.useServerPrepStmts=true
dataSource.useLocalSessionState=true
```

But I am not sure how to set these properties without explicitly creating bean of HikariDataSource as mentioned in this link: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1200

I am aspiring to set these properties directly via spring configuration file (property file or YML file)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172643/how-to-set-up-datasource-with-spring-for-hikaricp/24500712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These parameters can be easily configured via a simple configuration.

Just append these property/properties in standard spring datasource -> url property

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useLocalSessionState=true&cachePrepStmts=true&prepStmtCacheSize=250&prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
```

Similarly, other properties can be appended using *&* symbol.